# Java palindrome until EOF

Tags: java, eof, palindrome

I have a program that is supposed to ask the user for a number and it will determine whether it is a palindrome or not. It's supposed to keep asking for numbers until EOF is input - So far it asks for the number twice and doesn't seem to be doing the while loop correctly.

Any insight is appreciated

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class PalindromeEOF
{
public static void main(String args[])
{
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);        
    System.out.println("Enter a number to check if it is a palindrome:");

    String num = scanner.nextLine();
    String reverse = "";

    while (scanner.hasNextLine())
    {
        for ( int i = 0; i<num.length(); i++ )
        {
            reverse = num.charAt(i) + reverse;
        }
        if (num.equals(reverse))
        {
            System.out.println("\nEntered number IS a palindrome.");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("\nEntered number is NOT a palindrome.");
        }
        System.out.println("\nEnter a number to check if it is a palindrome:");
        num = scanner.nextLine();
        reverse = "";
    }
    System.out.println("\nProgram ended on request");
}
}
```

Comment: Where is `numAsString` declared?

Comment: my mistake, I changed that to num = scanner.nextLine(); instead of numAsString

Comment: Did you try running your code in debugger?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me; unless you need `num` or `reverse` outside the while loop it should work.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class PalindromeEOF
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);        
        System.out.println("Enter a number to check if it is a palindrome:");

        while (scanner.hasNextLine())
        {
            String num = scanner.nextLine();
            String reverse = "";

            for ( int i = 0; i<num.length(); i++ )
            {
                reverse = num.charAt(i) + reverse;
            }
            if (num.equals(reverse))
            {
                System.out.println("\nEntered number IS a palindrome.");
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("\nEntered number is NOT a palindrome.");
            }
            System.out.println("\nEnter a number to check if it is a palindrome:");

        }
        System.out.println("\nProgram ended on request");
    }
}
```

Comment: @Scary Wombat ^Z (control + Z) is the ASCII EOF sequence, and it ends the while loop.

Answer (score 0):

I would separate the palindrome test into its' own method. You could do that in a one line method like

```
public static boolean isPalindrome(String str) {
    return new StringBuilder(str).reverse().toString().equals(str);
}
```

but I would prefer to iterate the first half of the characters and compare them to the second half in reverse like

```
public static boolean isPalindrome(String str) {
    if (str == null) {
        return false;
    }
    char[] chars = str.toCharArray();
    for (int i = 0; i * 2 <= chars.length; i++) {
        if (chars[i] != chars[chars.length - i - 1]) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Then your `main` can invoke that in an infinite loop (terminating on the lack of input) like

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    while (true) {
        System.out.println("Enter a number to check if it is a palindrome:");
        if (!scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            break;
        }
        String num = scanner.nextLine();
        if (isPalindrome(num)) {
            System.out.printf("%s is a palindrome%n", num);
        } else {
            System.out.printf("%s is NOT a palindrome%n", num);
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Program ended on request");
}
```

Comment: @ScaryWombat Through the `scanner` `Scanner` reference, I did test this code so I'm not certain what you're getting at. One way it ends is when CTRL-d terminates the stdin stream.

Comment: ha, sorry I was reading as though user had to enter the String "EOF"